# JavaScript To Return Results From PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have the following set-up which the php piece of it runs as it should, I have tested and confirmed, which leads me to believe the issue is either

> 1) In my JavaScrip coding
>   2) In my set-up

This is my php file that I call

```
<?php
    $option = array(); 

    $option['driver']   = 'mssql';
    $option['host']     = 'host';
    $option['user']     = 'user';       
    $option['password'] = 'password';   
    $option['database'] = 'database';     
    $option['prefix']   = '';            

    $db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
    $result = $db->getQuery(true);
    $result->select($db->quoteName(array('trackandfieldresults')));
    $result->from($db->quoteName('[TrackData]')); 
    $db->setQuery($result); 
    $row = $db->loadRowList();
    print_r($row);
?>
```

And here is my syntax and attempt at a JavaScript call to get the data

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<div style="padding-top: 10px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="ajaxButton" /></div>
<div style="padding-top: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function() { makeRequest('Test.php'); };

  function makeRequest(url) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
</form>
```

What should be altered in the above syntax so that the result(s) are returned from my php file to my JavaScript function?

Each time I attempt to Execute I get the alert `There was a problem with the request`

**EDIT**
The dev tools shows a response of

> 500 Internal Server Error

And to ensure that the issue was not with ending the php file with `print_r` I altered the file to read like this so that I could confirm the result was being `echo`

```
$var = print_r($row, true);
echo $var
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: I would add to Jay's comment to check that the response code with dev tools to see if it's 200 or something else.

Comment: I am executing this with `Joomla`, is it possible to use the dev tools in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Is your table really called [TrackData]? or is it TrackData?